# How to copy text from one vi file to another vi file while using tmux

Tags: linux, vi, tmux

I am using tmux on a Linux server, and I am in two distinct directories on both tmux panes.

I have foo.txt open in pane 1, and bar.txt open in pane 2.

I want to copy text from pane 1 and move it to pane 2.

These were my steps:

1. Be in pane 1 (control+B, 0).
2. `vi foo.txt`
3. selecting text in VISUAL MODE followed by `"+y` in foo.txt
   (get the mesage "10 lines yanked")
4. Switching to pane 2 (control+B, 1)
5. `vi bar.txt`
6. and then hitting `p` when the file opened up in my terminal.

However, that did not work. How can I pull this off? I am using a Mac (keyboard) but the server is linux.

Comment: In case it helps, if you do not already know you can do :sp <FILENAME> to open the other file in same window and do what you are doing. CTRL+w+arrow will move you to  the other file you opened.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @IIIrnr101! is the :sp <FILENAME> command for vi?

Comment: Yes. tmux does not come into picture via this method.

Comment: I see what you are saying. However, that is precisely my problem. I am in two distinct directories on my two tmux panes. foo.txt is in ~/dir1/dir2/ while bar.txt is in ~/dir3/dir4, and one tmux pane is open in ~/dir1/dir2/ and the other is open in ~/dir3/dir4 @IIIrnr101

Comment: Sounds like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58763/copy-text-from-one-tmux-pane-to-another-using-vim)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had been dealt with this problem and wrote down a note on this here: https://github.com/g6ai/dotfiles/wiki/tmux.conf

Here I assume you are ssh-ing into Linux from macOS. You could found my tmux.conf in the same dotfiles repo.